# How to set a list of Models on a Collection with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, collections, data-manipulation

I'm trying to update a list of `models` from my `AppView` linked to my `Collection` but I'm not sure how should I do it.

I thought to do it on the `render` function, the purpose is to set a specific property I've called `treeId` which is `0` by default and I would change it to a different value after the rendering to set a different `treeId` html `attribute` inside the html template for every model.

```
render: function() {
    console.log("View - App.render");
    this.statusOpenedFolder();
    var parentTreeId = this.parentTreeId;

    _.each(this.collection.toJSON(), function (model, index) {
        model.treeId = parentTreeId + index;
        console.log("treeId edit " + model.treeId);
    });

    var assetsChildren = _.template(this.tmplAssetsChildren, {items:this.collection.toJSON()});
    this.$currentTarget.find("ul").remove();
    this.$currentTarget.append(assetsChildren);
    this.delegateEvents();

    return;
}
```

Basically i'll need it to get where is the children of a tree menu.

Obviously the `_.each` method don't work because I'm doing it without any reference to the collection, how can I do it?

Comment: you could create your view this way `new View(collection: new Collection())` , I am not sure if this answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this.collection.models` in your `_.each` function, or simply `this.collection.each`, as it's mixed in `Backbone.Collection`. However, I'm not sure if you want to recalculate it every time you render -- I guess `this.parentTreeId` doesn't change, so you may do it in `initialize`.